# Two Tkinter Images

Tags: python, image, user-interface, windows-7, tkinter

I have written a simple GUI in Python using the Tkinter library. This GUI has to display 2 images, one on top and one on the bottom. When I place the two images on the window, there seems to be a white line between the two. How to I place them so this doesn't show up?

I am programming on Windows 7 with Python 2.6

Comment: Can you paste the code somewhere?

Comment: Sure. http://pastebin.com/brRtvJGe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set border=0 and it seemed to eliminate the gap between the two stacked images.

```
panel1 = Label(root, border=0, image=p)
panel2 = Label(root, border=0, image=p)
```